# How do I properly cache a menu item that varies by user?

Tags: caching

We are attempting to show a users first name on a profile menu for authenticated users. We added a lazy builder to the `hook_preprocess_page` hook in our theme given this is highly dynamic content on heavily cached pages.

```
if ($account->isAuthenticated()) {
  $vars['current_user_first_name'] = [
    '#create_placeholder' => true,
    '#lazy_builder' => [
      '\Drupal\ourtheme\OurThemeLazyBuilders::getUserFirstName',
      [$account->id()]
    ]
  ];
}
```

With this callback (inside of a class that implements `RenderCallbackInterface`)

```
public static function getUserFirstName($account_id) {
    $user = User::load($account_id);
    return [
      '#plain_text' => $user->field_first_name->value,
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0
      ],
    ];
  }
```

However, when two of us (both `administrator` accounts) log in, whoever logs in second will see the other persons first name. We have verified the caching issue by setting a breakpoint in the `hook_preprocess_page` hook and see that the breakpoint never gets hit for the second users request. We tried moving the lazybuilder into it's own block and placing that block in a region of our theme, this didn't seem to make a difference, we saw the same caching behavior.

Interestingly, this only seems to happen when the users have the `administrator` role, we have thousands of other active users who only have `authenticated users` role and we've not heard anything about this issue from them (we would have heard immediately if there was an issue for general users).

Is there a way to debug the caching system in Drupal to know what parts of a page are cached by the dynamic cache and/or page cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass the user ID to the lazy builder, arguments get cached. Get the current user ID in the lazy builder:

```
public static function getUserFirstName() {
    $account_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
    $user = User::load($account_id);
    return [
      '#plain_text' => $user->field_first_name->value,
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0
      ],
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Would they also get better performance by setting a cache context for the current user instead of max-age?

Comment: Probably the opposite - it’s not recommended to vary by current user as that produces a lot of variations, and obviously increasing exponentially as the user base grows

Comment: Thank you! You have solved a few day old mystery....knew it had to be something like that!

Comment: @Clive is almost certainly correct.